# Xamarin Forms Sqlite UpdateAsync updating database

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, sql-update

Xamarin Forms 5

VS2019

Currently trying to update android only.

I've tried several different ways to update the database, but nothing seems to work. It seems to be updating cache, because if I select the same entry it has the changes, but even the ObservableCollection isn't being updated.

Here's the latest:

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using static Android.Resource;

#nullable disable

namespace Photography.Handbook.Models
{
    public partial class Aperture : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Aperture()
        {

        }
        //public Aperture()
        //{
        //    ShutterApertures = new HashSet<ShutterAperture>();
        //}

        [PrimaryKey]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }


        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
        public virtual ICollection<ShutterAperture> ShutterApertures { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Update Code

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(Aperture entity)
        {
            String databasePath = await DB.GetDatabaseFilePath();

        SQLiteAsyncConnection db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);
            
            var x = App.db.DBInstance.Query<Aperture>($"SELECT * FROM Aperture WHERE Id = '{entity.Id}'");
            if(x != null)
            {
                x[0].Name = entity.Name;
                x[0].Active = entity.Active;
                x[0].Notes = entity.Notes;

            var y = await db.UpdateAllAsync(x[0]);
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: first, INPC doesn't do anything useful if you don't call `OnPropertyChanged` in your setters.  Second, it's unclear what you expect to happen vs what is actually happening.  Is the problem that the database doesn't update, or that the UI isn't refreshing, or something else?

Comment: It's returning a value of 1 (y=1), which it should do if the database is updated. But there is no update.

Comment: how are you verifying that it is not updated?

Comment: Table values aren't changing.

Comment: How are you checking that?  Are you doing a query immediately after the update?  Are you using some db tool to look at the values?  Are you just verifying by what your app UI is displaying?

Comment: I use SqliteManager to look at the data.

Comment: are you **positive** that you are looking at the right copy of the sqlite file?  I strongly suspect that you are not

Comment: Yes, because if I change a value in SqliteManager it shows up  in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I was overwriting the database each time I re-started the app.

Thanks everyone for the suggestions.